# How to fix Jekyll Baseurl problems

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I'm making a theme for Jekyll, and I've hit a problem where the site only serves to `localhost:4000`, and when I add a `baseurl`, it ignores it, although the command line output says it is serving it to `localhost:4000/baseurl/`. The theme is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/forgenst/jekyll-statuspage).

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I think I've worked out the problem... see issue 3 - https://github.com/forgenst/jekyll-statuspage/issues/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Windows problem. See https://github.com/forgenst/jekyll-statuspage/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

Should be fixed when you use `{{ page.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}`.